# I want to navigate to full another url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, url-routing

I have a database for storing the url name and url.

I have shown the url from the database but when I try to navigate to the url it takes whole base url with it:

```
<h1>Useful Links</h1>

<ul class="latestnews">
  @foreach($importantLinks as $importantLink)
    <li>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{!! $importantLink->url !!}">  {!! $importantLink->name !!}</a></h4>
      </div>
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

It navigates to:

```
http://localhost/sabin/important_link/www.sabin.info.np
```

instead of:

```
http://sabin.info.np/
```

Comment: The `href` needs to be absolute. so in this case, you'd expect `$importantLink->url` to start with `http://` going by your information.

Comment: i am not getting you

Comment: Either, you need your `$importantLink->url` property to have `http://` at the beginning of the value. Or, if these are always going to be external / FQDN urls then `href="http://{!! $importantLink->url !!}"` would also work.